# Importing a paper wallet into Coinomi

Tags: bitcoin-core, coinomi

What exactly is happening when you take a picture of the QR code from a bitcoin paper wallet with the Coinomi app? Are you executing a transfer of bitcoin from the paper wallet to the Coinomi wallet that then has to be verified on the blockchain and pay the fees? Would you then have to pay again to transfer it back to your paper wallet?